# Why is Android studio not automatically cleaning my project

Tags: android-studio, build

I recently renamed my project by closing Android Studio, renaming the root project directory then opening A.S again.

A.S names the project using the new directory name, then I open it. A new *.iml* file is created with the new name. I deleted the old one and cleaned the project.

Everything went fine but now when I build it just deploys the app instead of cleaning it first. I have to manually clean it and it's annoying.

Is there a setting that might have gotten messed up?

---

Platform Details: Android Studio 3.0.1, Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So, apparently if you add flavors to your project then you have to manually clean the project otherwise when you build, Android Studio will launch the previous APK.